# Martingale and composition of function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

> Let $(Z_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent and bounded r.v. with $\mathbb{E}(Z_i)=m_i$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Z_i)=\sigma_i$. Let $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma({Z_1,\dots,Z_n})$. Find a $(b_n)$ such that for a $t\in\mathbb{R}$
>   $$b_n\exp\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^ntZ_i\right)$$
>   becomes a martingale.

I get stucked in this exercise because of the exponential function. What shall I do:
$$b_{n+1}\exp\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^ntZ_i\right)\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(tZ_{n+1}\right)\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right)$$
I can't compute $$\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(tZ_{n+1}\right)\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(tZ_{n+1}\right)\right)$$
Because it's a composition and I only know the expectation of $Z_i$, not of the composition. Do I have to make somehow a substitution?

Comment: It is not clear what $X_i$ is.

Comment: @Gordon My mistake. Should be $Z_i$

Comment: Then $E(e^{tZ_{n+1}}\mid F_n) = E(e^{tZ_{n+1}}) $.

Comment: Do you only know $E[Z_i]$ or also $E[Z_i^k]$ for $k\ge 1$? Because the expectation you want to find is the mgf of $Z_{n+1}$.

Comment: Likely, $Z_i$ should be normally distributed.

Comment: @JimmyR. I know $E(Z_i)$ and also $\operatorname{Var}(Z_i)=\sigma_i$

Comment: @Gordon Yes I know this, but I don't know how to compute $\mathbb{E}(e^{tZ_{n+1}})$ Is there some sort of trick like a substitution?

Comment: So, you know that they are normally distributed?

Comment: @JimmyR. No. I don't know anything about the distribution besides that $E(Z_i)=m_i$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Z_i)=\sigma_i$. Or do you mean that $\exp(tZ_i)$ is normally distributed?

Comment: Then the best you can do is to write that b_{n+1} is the moment generating function. You cannot do any better that IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Z_{n+1}$ is independent from $\mathcal F_n$ you have that $$\mathbb E[\exp(tZ_{n+1})\mid \mathcal F_n]=\mathbb E[\exp(tZ_{n+1})]$$ and the last term is the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples) (MGF) of $Z_{n+1}$, which you may denote with $M_{n+1}(t)$. Hence $$b_{n+1}\mathbb E[\exp(tZ_{n+1})]=1\implies b_{n+1}=\frac1{M_{n+1}(t)}$$ so the martingale becomes $$W_n:=\frac{\exp(tS_n)}{M_n(t)}$$ which is known as the [Wald's martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_martingale).

---

The most common case is when $Z_{n+1}\sim \mathcal N(m_{n+1},σ^2_{n+1})$, (Brownian motion) and  the MGF of $Z_{n+1}$ is given by $$M_{n+1}(t)=\mathbb E[\exp(tZ_{n+1})]=\exp\left(tm_{n+1}+\frac12σ^2_{n+1}t^2\right)$$ Hence $$b_{n+1}\mathbb E[\exp(tZ_{n+1})]=1\implies b_{n+1}=\exp\left(-tm_{n+1}-\frac12σ^2_{n+1}t^2\right)$$ and for $m_{n+1}=0, σ^2_{n+1}=σ^2$ this becomes $$W_n=\exp\left(tS_n-\frac12σ^2t^2\right)$$ (also known with continuous time, $t\ge0$, instead of discrete $n\ge0$).

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks a lot for accepting it!